# Can't override Twitter Bootstrap Button with @extend .btn;?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, button, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the folowing in my stylsheet.scss:

```
   @import "bootstrap";

    .navbar .nav > li > a.btn.btn-success {
     @extend .btn;
     @extend .btn-success;
```

In Rails I have the following line in my header

```
    <li><%= link_to 'Post A Ride', home_path, :class => "btn btn-success" %></li>
```

The problem is the button is still inheriting from the li and a classes even though when I use  Google Chrome's Inspect Element it recognizes .navbar .nav > li > a.btn.btn-success {
     @extend .btn;
     @extend .btn-success;
**first** and it looks ugly / not like the original button.

What am I missing here?

```
  <header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
   <div class="container"> 

   <%= link_to "ALift", '#', id: "logo" %>
   <nav>
   <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li><%= link_to 'Post A Ride', home_path, :class => "btn btn-success" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Search",  '#' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: try importing bootstrap responsive as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use extends, the corresponding CSS declarations appear at the top of the resulting CSS file.

That's just how extends work in SASS and there's not much you can do, but here's a couple of workarounds for you to consider:

- **Use extend to produce a longer selector sequence.** If your extended selector sequence will be more [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), it will prevail over the default style even though the default one appears later in code.
- **Recreate the styles manually without making use of the extend.** If you avoid extending, your styles will appear in normal order. If they appear below the default styles, they will be effective even though they have the same specificity.

### UPD 1

Okay, now when you've provided more info, i can see that in your Chrome screenshot you've got the `.navbar .nav > li > a.btn.btn-success` rule without any declarations.

Please have a look in the compiled CSS file and find that rule. Is it empty or not? When you compile your SASS, do you receive any warnings?

Please update your question again AND post a follow-up comment to my answer.

### UPD 2

Okay, now it is clear that your SCSS is not compiled. Do you link your SCSS file directly from the HTML?

No browser is capable of rendering SCSS/SASS. For it to work, you have to compile SASS into regular CSS and serve the CSS.

And/or there might be an issue with Bootstrap. The original Bootstrap is not powered by SASS. It's written in LESS and supposed to be used by importing a bloated static CSS file (over 100KB, yikes!). SASS does allow you importing static CSS files, but it's unable to extend classes declared there.

There are a couple of SASS ports of Bootstrap (google `bootstrap sass`). They might allow you apply styles semantically, resulting in a much smaller CSS. And they should allow extending any of their classes too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I don't understand your answer or if we are misunderstanding each other. I want it to use the @extend so the button looks like the original as it should. I added more code and image at the top.

Comment: Updated my answer asking even more info from you. :)

Comment: Added another screenshot. No warnings. As you can see the style.scss is populated. Still missing something. Thanks for the positive response.

Comment: I have been doing some research: must the style file be css.scss or scss.css or what? It seems all tutorials says .css.scss, but when I do that it doesn't pull the code in recognize it.

Comment: Once again, you have to **compile** the SCSS code to produce CSS. Here's a nice article to begin with: http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass And don't forget to accept my answer. ^_^

Comment: This is getting heavy. I give up now. Thanks and appreciate it.

Comment: Hey @ErinWalker, starting web development with SASS and Compass is heavy indeed, but you should totally give it a try! Please read this overview to find out what it pays you for your extra effort: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16230199/901944